# is it possible to add data to 3 tables in one database at the same time

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

i want to add data in 3 tables in one database from 3 AsyncTask object. because the AsyncTask objects may run or finish at the same time and i'm adding data in my database in onPostExecute() , i want to know is it possible to do such a thing or not ?
thanx

Comment: It sounds as if the `executeOnExecutor()` method in the `AsyncTask` class would be relevant here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Params...) - However, as I don't have any personal experience using it I'll leave this as a comment in case someone else can answer more fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android `SQLiteOpenHelper` is synchronized by default. all you need to do is make your DB helper singleton and you will not face any problem.

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905524/using-singleton-design-pattern-for-sqlitedatabase) for more info on singleton db helper.

Comment: ty , you mean if i use simple SQLiteDatabase objects and use them for insert and select , it may cause problems ?

Comment: Worth keeping in mind that [Android Design Patterns](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html "synchronized getInstance()") also recommend making the `getInstance()` method `synchronized` for this reason.

Comment: i already write my all codes with SQLiteDatabase  , is there a better way to i use this class rather than SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Comment: @Pirisok `SqliteOpenHelper` is [officially recommended](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) way