# Long lived database reference / proper database setup

Tags: java, android

What is the proper way to keep a reference to your `SQLiteDatabase` through out the lifespan of your application?

Currently, I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class myApp {
    public static SQLiteDatabase DB;

    //...
}
```

Then in my class that extends `Application`, `onCreate()` I check if `myApp.DB` is `null` and if it is, create a new `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and set it to `getWritableDatabase()`. Through out my app, I reference `myApp.DB` for various queries and such.

This works fine under local testing purposes, but others are experiencing instances where this creates strange behavior (Mostly when trying to determine a table's existence by using `select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'myTable'`) -- at a guess, I'm thinking that something is happening to cause the `myApp.DB` reference to be GCed. This makes me believe I need to do that same check for null before interacting with the database, but I don't like the idea of making that check before every single DB interaction (possibly by wrapping all queries in my own method that calls that check first).

So what is the best practice to maintain a reliable reference to your database? Should I instead be keeping a reference to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` and do `getWriteableDatabase` before every interaction?

Comment: see [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-working-with-content-providers--mobile-5549)

Comment: And possibly [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905524/using-singleton-design-pattern-for-sqlitedatabase)