# Difficulty creating a database using dbhepler

Tags: android, database

I am trying to develop an app using the class dbhelper.I have to create 15 different activities using the class dbhelper.I am finding it difficult to call the dphelper for each and every activity.can i get some suggestions.

Comment: Make a static factory method. Access or get instance of the dbHelper by calling this static method.

Comment: You can trying with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905524/using-singleton-design-pattern-for-sqlitedatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905524/using-singleton-design-pattern-for-sqlitedatabase) that flow