# How does the Singleton Pattern maintains State?

Tags: android, design-patterns, singleton

Can someone please tell me how I can apply the *Singleton* Design Pattern to **maintain state** and keep the **UI** of my Android application **synchronized** with the application’s **data**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Singleton design pattern for SQLiteDatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905524/using-singleton-design-pattern-for-sqlitedatabase)

Comment: That is a very broad question. I suggest that you narrow it down, such as by explaining your specific use case (i.e., what is your state? what is your UI?).