# Android Db locked

Tags: android

Using Sqlite db, I am populating my list. That List is refreshed every minute(using Timer). Also I am updating/inserting Sqlite db(using Service), checking for new data.

This is also happening every minute. This is working but sometimes "Database is getting locked". How can I manage this and not get that error.  Appreciate your input.

```
public class Services extends Service {

Context context;
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
NotificationManager notificationManager, chatNotificationManager;
boolean connected = false;
boolean notconnected = false;
int numChat = 0;
int numTask = 0;
List<String> list =  new ArrayList();
String android_id, syncDecision;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override 
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
} 

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    context = getBaseContext();

    /*
     * THIS TIMER CONTAINS ANY SERVICE THAT ACCESSES THE SQLite database
     */
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "starting to do work in timer1");
            synchronizeSQLiteDatabases();
        }
    }, 0, 60000);


private void synchronizeSQLiteDatabases() {
    try {

        if (Functions.isOnline(context) )
        {
        // ---------------------------------- COMMENT UPLOAD ----------------------------
        if (!((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid().equals("000000")) {
             try
             {
                Log.i(TAG, "uploading comment data");
                DataUploader_Comment commentupdater = new DataUploader_Comment(((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid(), 
                        ((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getPassword(), context);
                commentupdater.run();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                    Log.i(TAG, "    CATCH uploading comment data" + e.toString());

             }
        }
        else
        {
            //Functions.logout(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i(TAG, "    NOT uploading comment data");
        }
        //--------------------------------------- TASK UPLOAD --------------------------------
        if ( !((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid().equals("000000")) {

                try{
                    Log.i(TAG, "uploading task data");
                    DataUploader_Task taskuploader = new DataUploader_Task(((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid(), 
                        ((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getPassword(), context);
                    taskuploader.run();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "    CATCH uploading task data" + e);

                }
        }
        else
        {
            //Functions.logout(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i(TAG, "    NOT uploading task data");
        }

        // ------------------------------------------AC DOWNLOAD ---------------------------------
        if (!((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid().equals("000000")) {


                try{
                    Log.i(TAG, "running aircraft data download");
                    DataLoader_Aircraft acloader = new DataLoader_Aircraft(((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid(), 
                        ((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getPassword(), context, "N");
                    acloader.run();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "    CATCH running aircraft data download" + e.toString());

                }
        }
        else
        {
            //Functions.logout(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i(TAG, "    NOT running aircraft data download");
        }

        // ------------------------------------ TASK DOWNLOAD ------------------------------------
        if (  !((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid().equals("000000")) {

            try{
                Log.i(TAG, "running task data download");
                DataLoader_Task tasksloader = new DataLoader_Task(((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid(), 
                        ((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getPassword(), context, "N");
                tasksloader.run();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, " CATCH running task data download" + e.toString());

            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Functions.logout(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i(TAG, "    NOT running task data download");
        }

        // -------------------------------- EMPLOYEE DOWNLOAD -----------------------------------
        if (!((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid().equals("000000")) {

            try
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "running employee data download");
                DataLoader_Employee employeeloader = new DataLoader_Employee(((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid(), 
                        ((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getPassword(), context, "N");
                employeeloader.run();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "    CATCH running employee data download " + e.toString());

            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Functions.logout(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i(TAG, "    NOT running employee data download");
        }

        // ------------------------------------COMMENT DOWNLOAD -----------------------------------------
        if (!((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid().equals("000000")) {

            try{
                Log.i(TAG, "running comment data update");
                DataLoader_Comment commentloader = new DataLoader_Comment(((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getUserid(), 
                        ((GlobalMobileVianet) this.getApplication()).getPassword(), context, "N");
                commentloader.run();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "    CATCH running comment data update" + e.toString());

            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Functions.logout(getApplicationContext());
            Log.i(TAG, "    NOT running comment data download");
        }

        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "synchronizeSQLiteDatabases exception: " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

and this is activity which refreshes the list

```
public class TestExList extends ExpandableListActivity{

 String empid, ctext, fleet_name, rString;
 private DbAdapter_Assignment assignment;
 private DbAdapter_Task task;
 private DbAdapter_Comment comment;
 private DbAdapter_Aircraft aircraft;
 private Cursor accursor, taskcursor;
 private ExpandableListView expListView;
 private Timer taskTimer;
 private ListView lv;
 private Camera cam;
 private boolean onoff;

 private boolean testValue;

 private SimpleCursorTreeAdapter cursorTreeAdapter;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        empid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EmpID");
        Log.d("testValue","from onCreate, onoff is " + onoff);

        setHeader();

        if(empid.equals(Functions.getLoginEmpID(this))){
            getData(empid);
        }
        taskTimer = new Timer();
        taskTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerMethod();
            }

        }, 0, 60000);
        expListView.invalidateViews();
    } 


    private void TimerMethod()
    {
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                if(Functions.getServiceStatus(getBaseContext()) != "No service")
                {
                    if(empid.equals(Functions.getLoginEmpID(getBaseContext())))
                    {
                        getData(empid);
                    }
                }
        }
    };
    @Override 
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        try
        {
            accursor.close();
            taskcursor.close();
            task.close();
            comment.close();
            aircraft.close();
            assignment.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("ViaNetError", "Unable to close cursors.");
        }

        if(cam != null)
        {
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
    }


    public void getData(final String empid)
    {
         Log.e("Testing", "Getting data for emp: " + empid);
        assignment =  new DbAdapter_Assignment(getBaseContext());
         assignment.open();
         task =  new DbAdapter_Task (getBaseContext());
         task.open();
         comment = new DbAdapter_Comment (getBaseContext());
         comment.open();

    }
    }
```

Comment: May want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302286/android-simultaneous-db-operations-database-is-locked

Comment: Are you using more than one DbHelper?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing, but getData reassign `assignment`, `task` and `comment` without to close previous values. What happens if you write `if(assignment != null) { assignment.close() } [...]`  for each variable previously opened ?

Comment: If I close that every time. It errors out "trying to read closed"

Answer (score 2):

I fought with this exact same problem for ages, randomly with using my app an opening of the db would get a "db is locked" with no rime or reason. After struggling for several months this was my solution.

1) Create you dbopenhelper in class with all of its methods like normal.

2) Create an instance of that class in your APPLICATION class.

3) Open the DB in the onCreate of the Application class, and never close it ever.

4) Run all queries through the Application class owned copy of the dbhelper.

I was worried about never closing the DB, but my research showed many instances of Android developers (IE Googles folks) suggesting just that.

Hope it works as well for you as it has for me.

Comment: I tried this approach But not working in my case please take look at my question [link is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859840/application-crashes-on-installation-with-error-sqlite3-exec-failed-to-set-sync)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is telling you the database is already opened in an other thread. You have to use SQLite in a thread-safe way.

Could you add your code in your question where you open your database and the timer ?